# Tesseract - NameError: name 'Output' is not defined

Tags: python, image, output, python-tesseract, undefined-reference

I'm using tesseract for the OCR part , but I've run into a small setback with defining the output. Could anyone help me out in resolving this issue

```
details = pytesseract.image_to_data(threshold_img, output_type=Output.DICT, config=custom_config, lang='eng')
```

It caused an error

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-0b2393b8b9e3> in <module>
----> 1 details = pytesseract.image_to_data(threshold_img, output_type=Output.DICT, config=custom_config, lang='eng')

NameError: name 'Output' is not defined
```

Comment: try this post from livezingy [Define Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60009533/drawing-bounding-boxes-with-pytesseract-opencv) . Seems like the Output in your code is not defined. Pls, share the complete code so we can take a further look.

Comment: Have you imported the `Output` in your code ? like `from pytesseract import Output
` ?

Comment: Yes @Kris  , I did import the output from pytesseract. Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: Sure @simpleApp I'll have a look at it. Thanks for your time to review and get back.